# U.S. Employee teleworking while traveling in Italy

Tags: usa

U.S. Citizen and Staff Person for U.S. based university, is traveling in Italy, staying with a friend, for 90 days.

I want them to do web based work while traveling, and pay them for the hours worked, likely 15 hours per week. We want to meet every standard that the Italian Government has.  Seeking as much information and insight as possible.  Is this 90 day period just a vacation, all of us do some form of work for our companies while traveling?